# Binary calculator

Tags: java, calculator, number-systems

I made a Binary Calculator that gives the user's the decimal value of their input.

I tried to make my code as small as possible but I feel like there's still too much lines of code for such a simple program.

Did I overcomplicate this too much? Is there a way I could improve?

**BinaryCalc class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;

public class BinaryCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean keepGoing = false;

        /*
         * Ask the user to input a binary
         */
        System.out.print("Please enter a binary number : ");
        String str = input.nextLine();
        int size = str.length();

        /*
         * Check if the user's input doesn't go over '1'
         */
        for (int s = 0; s < size; s++) {
            if (str.charAt(s) != '0' && str.charAt(s) != '1') {
                System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
                size = 0;
                main(args);
                break;
            } else {
                keepGoing = true;
            }

        }

        /*
         * Use the formula [(bit * base) ^ position]
         */
        if (keepGoing = true) {
            int total = 0;
            int result = 0;
            int position = 0;

            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                int bit = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
                result = (int) (bit * (Math.pow(2, position)));
                total += result;
                position++;
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fix a bug in the second condition

First of all, you have a bug in the second condition:

```
if (keepGoing = true) {
```

this expression assigns true to `keepGoing` and then returns true as a result. Thus, `if` always executes which leads to extra results showing up for invalid inputs.

You probably wanted to check the value of a keepGoing with `==`:

```
if(keepGoing==true) {
```

this will work, but you should never compare boolean values with true or false. Using the value itself is more convenient:

```
if(keepGoing) {
```

Also, the name `keepGoing` doesn't say anything about the actual condition. It's unclear in which cases the code is going forward. I suggest renaming it to `isBinary`:

```
if(isBinary) {
```

### Fix a bug in the control flow

You're setting `isBinary` to true on each valid character and you're not setting it back to false when the character is invalid:

```
if (str.charAt(s) != '0' && str.charAt(s) != '1') {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
    size = 0;
    main(args);
    break;
} else {
    isBinary = true;
}
```

So, if the input string starts with a valid character (e.g. `119`) the code will set `isBinary` to true which will again lead to extra results.

Instead, you can set it to false on an invalid character:

```
boolean isBinary = true;
if (str.charAt(s) != '0' && str.charAt(s) != '1') {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
    size = 0;
    main(args);
    isBinary = false;
    break;
}
```

The rest of this method executes only if `isBinary` is true, so, at this point, you can just return from the method:

```
if (str.charAt(s) != '0' && str.charAt(s) != '1') {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
    main(args);
    return;
}
```

after that, you don't need to check for `isBinary` and set `size` to zero. The code will get to calculation only if the input doesn't contain invalid characters

Code so far:

```
/*
* Check if the user's input doesn't go over '1'
*/
for (int s = 0; s < size; s++) {
    if (str.charAt(s) != '0' && str.charAt(s) != '1') {
        System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
        main(args);
        return;
    }
}

/*
* Use the formula [(bit * base) ^ position]
*/
int total = 0;
int result = 0;
int position = 0;

for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int bit = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
    result = (int) (bit * (Math.pow(2, position)));
    total += result;
    position++;
}
```

### Additional clean-up

`result` is only used once, let's move it closer to usage:

```
int result = (int) (bit * (Math.pow(2, position)));
total += result;
```

The `size` is not updated anymore and seems unnecessary: let's replace it with actual length:

```
for (int s = 0; s < str.length(); s++) {
...
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

### Introduce helper methods

You have two independent blocks of code: the first one reads and validates the input, the second converts it to decimal. You can move validation and calculation into separate methods:

```
/**
 * Check if the user's input doesn't go over '1'
 */
private static boolean isBinary(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != '0' && str.charAt(i) != '1') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Use the formula [(bit * base) ^ position]
 */
private static int toDecimal(String str) {

    int total = 0;
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int bit = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
        int result = (int) (bit * (Math.pow(2, position)));
        total += result;
        position++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

As you can see, I moved comments as well and turned them into javadoc format.

Now, the `main` method control flow is easier to read and understand:

```
if (!isBinary(str)) {
   System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
   main(args);
   return;
}
System.out.println(toDecimal(str));
```

### Check for an empty string

It seems like new `isBinary` method introduced a bug: it will return true for an empty string. We can go ahead and add an extra condition:

```
if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
}
```

### Get rid of recursion

The recursive call to a `main` breaks the flow and is hard to read and understand. Recursion is usually used to change the scope of a method. If you just want to repeat the same action multiple times, you can use a loop:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a binary number : ");
String str = input.nextLine();
while (!isBinary(str)) {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number : ");
    str = input.nextLine();
}
```

and move the duplicated lines into a separate method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = promptInput(input);
    while (!isBinary(str)) {
        System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
        str = promptInput(input);
    }
    System.out.println(toDecimal(str));
}

/**
 * Ask the user to input a binary
 */
private static String promptInput(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number : ");
    return input.nextLine();
}
```

### Consider alternatives

Now the control flow is relatively clear we can think about improving the actual calculation in `toDecimal` and `isBinary`

A quick research on StackOverflow returns multiple questions on this topic, to name a few:

- [How to convert binary string value to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal)
- [How to convert a Binary String to a base 10 integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178980/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-base-10-integer-in-java)
- [Check that a String entered contains only 1's and 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809914/check-that-a-string-entered-contains-only-1s-and-0s)

We can use suggestions from there and replace the calculation with shorter alternatives:

```
/**
 * Check if the user's input doesn't go over '1'
 */
private static boolean isBinary(String str) {
    return str.matches("[01]+");
}

/**
 * Use the formula [(bit * base) ^ position]
 */
private static int toDecimal(String str) {
    return Integer.parseInt(str, 2);
}
```

Now, both methods are self-explanatory one-liners and each of them is used only once. You can keep them or you can inline both of them:

```
String str = promptInput(input);
while (!str.matches("[01]+")) {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter a '0' or '1'");
    str = promptInput(input);
}
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str, 2));
```

One can argue that the code is easier to read with method calls because they show the intent. But at the end, it's a matter of taste/experience.

### Integer overflow

The code doesn't handle the case when the input number doesn't fit into the range of `Integer`. Original code will silently return a wrong value. `Integer.parseInt` will throw an exception. You'll need to think about that.

Comment: Wow @default locale! These are some amazing advices, thank you! I'm currently a beginner with Java and I've learned quite some things from your well written advices. Thanks again!

Comment: there's only one thing that I didn't understand. What do you mean by "As you can see, I moved comments as well and turned them into javadoc format."?

Comment: @Crypto I moved inline comments (e.g. `Check if the user's input doesn't go over`) to respective methods and added an extra asterisk `/**` required by javadoc.  [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) is a documentation generator for Java. IDEs use it to display help information.

Comment: Okay I see, I'll try to read more and learn how to make my code look more professional!